# Let $f,g \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ , $f(x)+g(x)=5$ and $f(g(x))=8-4x $ find $g(2)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis, functions

Let  $f,g$ are two polynomials  $f,g \in \mathbb{R}[x]$  such that $f(x)+g(x)=5$ and $f(g(x))=8-4x $ .

> Find set of all possible values of $g(2)$.

Let $\deg f=n , \deg g=m$ so $\deg f(g(x)) \le mn$ so $mn=1$ then $m=n=1$ then $f(x)=ax+b$ and $g(x)=cx+d$

We have $f(g(2))=0$

Comment: You are on the right track. Now plug in your linear forms into the two equations to get conditions on $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: Please write a more *informative* title.

Comment: Actually, $\deg f(g(x))=mn$

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed both $f$ and $g$ have to be of the form $a_0+a_1x$ and so lets set $g(x)=a_0+a_1x$. From the equations above:

$f(x)=5-a_0-a_1x$

$5-a_0-a_1(a_0+a_1x)=8-4x \iff a_0+a_0a_1+a_1^2x=-3+4x$

and so from the second equation $a_0+a_0a_1=-3$ and $a_1^2=4$, because "two polynomials are considered equal if they have equal coefficients of corresponding powers of the independent variable".

Can you proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$f(g(x))=8-4x\implies $$
$$f'(g(x))f'(x)=4$$
because

$$g'(x)=-f'(x)$$

So, necessarily, $ f(X)=aX+b$ with
$$a^2=4$$

and
$$g(X)=5-aX-b$$

thus
$$f(g(x))=a(5-ax-b)+b$$
$$=-a^2x+5a-ab+b=8-4x$$

there are two solutions
$$(a,b)\in\{(2,2),(-2,6)\}$$